# Using \n correctly?

Tags: c#

My code searches through a list and then if it finds a match, it displays the object in my listbox. My problem is that if there is more than 1 object in the list (if im searching for Alex and there is two objects with the name Alex), it returns it all on the same line instead of separating them to separate lines.

I coulda swore `match += request + "\n";` was how  to do it correctly, but it's not working.

Edit: One thing I dont understand is that if i just have `match += request;` it will allow me to use the horizontal scroll bar on my listbox to see everything written. And if i use `match += request + "\n";` or `match += request + Environment.NewLine;` it doesn't let me use the scroll box and just cuts off.

```
 public string SearchRequest(string keyword)
    {
        bool found = false;
        string noMatch = "No requests with the name " + "'" + keyword + "'" + " were found";
        string match = "";

        foreach (ServiceRequest request in Requests)
        {
            if (request.searchKeywords(keyword))
            {
                match += request + "\n";
                found = true;                    
            }
        }
        if (found)
            return match;
        else
            return noMatch;
    }
```

/

```
public bool searchKeywords(string keyword)
    {
        if (keyword == name)
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    }
```

/

```
 private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lstSearch.Items.Clear();
            lstSearch.Items.Add(myRequest.SearchRequest(txtSearch.Text));

        }
```

Comment: `\r\n` windows or Environment.NewLine is better unless putting it in a text file

Comment: If I understand your problem, you add a string item to a listbox with a newline and you expect to see two items, but this is not how the listbox items collection works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put all the results in a single string then it will still be a single item in the list.

Return an array of strings from the method instead of a single string:

```
public string[] SearchRequest(string keyword) {
    List<string> match = new List<string>();
    foreach (ServiceRequest request in Requests) {
        if (request.searchKeywords(keyword)) {
            match.Add(request.ToString());
        }
    }
    if (match.Count > 0) {
        return match.ToArray();
    } else {
        return new string[] { "No requests with the name " + "'" + keyword + "'" + " were found" };
    }
}
```

Then use `AddRange` to add the strings as separate items in the list:

```
lstSearch.Items.AddRange(myRequest.SearchRequest(txtSearch.Text));
```

Comment: An example of [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) :-)

Comment: @Guffa at `match.Add(request)` it is giving me an error. It says the best overloaded method match has some invalid arguements

Comment: @Alex: Aha, you have an implicit conversion to string in the concatenation. When there is no concatenation you need an explicit conversion, I added that above.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
match += request + Environment.NewLine;
```

Comment: Still not working. One thing I dont understand is that if i just have `match += request;` it will allow me to use the horizontal scroll bar on my listbox to see what's written. And if i use `match += request; + "\n"` or Environment.NewLine it doesn'tlet me use the scrollbox and just cuts off after the start of the second match it finds.

Comment: @Alex don't forget to escape your slashes `match += "\\n"` - actually that's a lie.. that would result in the literal "\n" - forget I said anything haha :D

Comment: @Alex Show how looks your ServiceRequest

Answer (score 0):

In Windows OS, the new line is two characters, the Carriage Return `\r` followed by Line Feed: `\n`. You can use `Environment.NewLine` as a shortcut (preferred) or append `"\r\n"` yourself. See further [wikipedia entry on newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)

Answer (score 0):

Use one of these:

```
match += request + "\r\n";
```

Use an string literal:

```
match += request + @"
";
```

OR only at runtime will this resolve:

```
match += request + System.Environment.NewLine;
```

On Unix `"\n"`

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a string with newlines to a listbox and expect it to show up as multiple items. Either split the string on newline and add each line separately to the listbox, or return a list of strings from your search function to begin with, avoiding the need for a split afterwards.